# C++ method calls from the same class

Tags: c++

In C++, I want to be able to call a method in the same class without creating an object of the whole class. The class is huge and I do not want to create a huge memory location for an object. I am used to programming in C#.

In C# I could do this

```
class test()
{
 private void A()
 {
    B();
 }

 private void B()
 {
    doSomething;
 }
}
```

in C++ I am under the impression I have to do.

```
class test()
{
  public:
         static void A();
         void B();
};


 void test::A()
 {
    test t;
    t.B();
 }

 void test::B()
 {
    doSomething;
 }
}
```

I do not want to make B() static nor do I want to create and object of test because in reality my class is a lot larger than this, and creating a object of the class would use memory that I do not want to.

Is there a way I can accomplish what I could in C# in C++?

Comment: What errors do you get when you try the first in C++? You will need to put `B()` first so the compiler can find it.

Comment: A class method you want to call without creating class object should be static, and it can not modify anything that is not static.
So, no matter what, if a function is not static, then you have to create the object before calling it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  If B needs an object, you have to give it an object.  If B doesn't need an object, declare it `static`.  C# is no different -- in your example, `A` is not static so the object already exists.

Comment: so in the c++ example if A() was not static I would not have to make an object inside of A() of test to call B()?

Comment: @user1601045 yes, because non-static methods already have the object that they were called on. If a method needs an object to operate on, it can't be static. If it doesn't need an object to operate on, it should be static.

Comment: @user1601045: correct, because `A` would already be part of an object, it could simply use that same object for `B`.

Answer (score 3):

```
     static void A();
     void B();
```

You cannot use `static` function to call non-static one at all.

**Solution**:
Mark `B` as `static` too (if it doesn't depend on current object) and thus you don't have to creat a new object. Else I think `A` should be non-static.